# MS Access Record Transfer

Tags: sql, ms-access

Good afternoon! I am hoping you may be able to help me, or at least point me in the right direction.

Some work is being moved between two servers at work, and SOME of the data in the database needs to be moved, but some needs to stay behind.

I can sort the records that need to be moved by office name, however each record potentially has records linked in a separate table - I can move the basic records across using simple copy and paste append.

Is there a way for copy to include a linked record? I have done some fruitless googling and struggled thus far, I'm not sure exactly what syntax to search for!

I'm not asking for it to be done for me, just a gentle nudge in the right direction would be helpful :)

Comment: One of the reasons your Google search may have been fruitless .. Is there really is no way for msaccess, mysql, or ms sql to "know" what tables are linked based on field names ...  This is why building a schematic of your database is always a good idea prior to the database becoming so large, that you personally can't remember what's connected to what.  --  There are tools out there that will build these relational maps for you, but I am personally unfamiliar enough with msaccess to be able to name any.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, luckily the database has only two tables that are connected by one field - say customer ID exists in Table A and is the only thing that links it to Table B - so in theory if it exists in Table B, it needs to move with the record in Table A - not sure if a database that 'simple' changes anything, but thought I would add?

Comment: There is an import function for MS access to SQL Server. I would recommend you google that and import both Table A and B to SQL.

Comment: I don't exactly understand your question. What do you mean with "linked record"? if there's a relationship linking the two, you can just also copy the linked data with a query

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth that is basically exactly correct, my syntax was poor - I will have to read up on database queries :)